# How does SQL UNION operator identify duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

Executing the following SQL (on an PostgreSQL data base) results in 9 rows, even tough the data sets from both tables are obviously not completely identical.

```
removed
```

Result:

```
removed
```

Why does it not result in 13 rows?

Using `UNION ALL` does the trick, but I am wondering how SQL `UNION` operator identifies duplicates?

Comment: There could be multiple ways. Why are you exactly interested in this one? You can access to the postgres code in this github project: https://github.com/postgres/postgres

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` removes duplicates *from the result set*.  It guarantees that the result has no duplicates at all.  So, it removes duplicates both within tables and between tables.

You seem to have total duplicates within the tables.  They are removed.

Comment: As far as I see in the question, he already knows that `UNION` behaves like that... But he asks about how exactly works the _DISTINCT_ function called by the `UNION` clause

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . When I learned about `UNION` it wasn't clear to me that it removed duplicates *within* a table.  That was a long, long time ago, but I still remember having to learn that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes Gordon, totally agree, the `UNION` clause is not that obvious. But based in the text, literally, he/she wonders "how SQL UNION operator identifies duplicates". It could be asking about if the engine does a _hash_ of each record to identify it, or a _checksum_ or wathever...

Comment: The answer from @GordonLinoff was all I needed know. Thanks!

Comment: @JaimeDrq It's not what OP asks for, but two things are considered equal if the equality operator returns `TRUE`. Two composite values (rows) are equal exactly when all their elements are equal.